# Сравнение двух html документов

Tags: html

Есть верстка, сделана верстальщиком. Когда шаблонизируешь html оживляя веб-станицу функционалом, можно легко потерять какой то закрывающийся тэг, добавить лишний, что то ещё накосячить. 
В общем эти ошибки находятся сравнением вёрстки и результирующего хтмл, иногда догадываешься по посыпавшимся элемнетам, но уходит на это порой куча времени.
Вопрос состоит в том, нет ли такого инструмента, который бы сравнивал ДОМ модель двух документов в независимости от контента и выдавал какой то понятный дифф, где именно ты лошара?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Firefox есть расширение [PageDiff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pagediff/). Также я нашёл расширение [DOM Diff](http://www.mugo.ca/Extensions-and-Tools/Products/Dom-Diff), но не смог его установить. Возможно, вам повезёт больше.

Answer (score 0):

В IDE ошибки подсвечиваются. Сразу видно, где забыл закрыть тэг и прочее.